# Ajax-PHP doesnt work as expected

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to build a page with AJAX and PHP to printout the database

index.php

```
 <div id='mainTable'>
      <table border=1>
            <tr><th class='col1'>Mã Sinh Viên</th>
                <th class='col2'>Họ tên</th>
                <th class='col3'>Ngày sinh</th>
                <th class='col4'>Giới tính</th>
                <th class='col5'>Địa chỉ</th>
            </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<script>
function showPage(page) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)   {
        xmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else    {
        xmlhttp= new ActiveObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()   {
        if(xmlhttp.readystate==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)    {
            $("#mainTable table").append(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","showStudent.php?page="+page,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
     }

  $(document).ready(function(){
  showPage(1);
  });
  </script>
```

showStudent.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$db= new mysqli("localhost","root","","student");
if(!isset($_GET['page']))   {
    $page=1;
}
else    {
    $page= $_GET['page'];
}
$start= ($page-1)*10;
$result= $db->query("SELECT * FROM information LIMIT $start,10");
while($row= $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $stuId= $row['stuId'];
    $stuName= $row['stuName'];
    $stuDob= $row['stuDoB'];
    $stuSex= $row['stuDoB']?'Nam':'Nữ';
    $stuAdd= $row['stuAdd'];
    echo    "<tr><td class='col1'>$stuId</td>
            <td class='col2'>$stuName</td>
            <td class='col3'>$stuDoB</td>
            <td class='col4'>$stuSex</td>
            <td class='col5'>$stuAdd</td>
            </tr>
            ";  
    }
$_SESSION['page']= $page;
  ?>
```

As I expected,when the page load it must print out a table from the database,but I only got blank field.I tried another way with PHP code and it worked so I think the problem is about AJAX.
Can someone help me out,what is problem with my AJAX code ?

Comment: Do you consider using jQuery's AJAX?

Comment: Try some debugging method, like `console.log` in JS and `var_dump`/`print_r` in PHP to see if something is unexpected.

Comment: I dont get the word "consider" ? @@

Comment: @DucAnh Okay, lemme say this way: Use jQuery's AJAX!!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this part:

```
<script>
function showPage(page) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)   {
        xmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else    {
        xmlhttp= new ActiveObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()   {
        if(xmlhttp.readystate==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)    {
            $("#mainTable table").append(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","showStudent.php?page="+page,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
     }

  $(document).ready(function(){
  showPage(1);
  });
  </script>
```

With:

```
<script>
function showPage(page) {
    $.get("showStudent.php?page="+page, function(data){
        $("#mainTable table").append(data);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    showPage(1);
});
</script>
```

Comment: `$.get` returns an XHR object. You have to do the appending inside of a `success` callback.

Comment: @Blender Updating the answer. I was referring to. :)

Comment: @Blender Please check now?

Comment: Im new to Ajax and tks to you now I know about Jquery Ajax :D

Comment: Sure... :) When it supports a lot of features, the basic support would be AJAX. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo (or you just did it wrong). `xmlhttp.readystate` should be `xmlhttp.readyState`, notice the capital S. Also what's an `ActiveObject`?

Comment: Oh what a mistake ! I fixed it,tks guy

Comment: that should be `ActiveXObject` http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajaxbrowsersupport.php